# Unpermitted parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Buen día, mi problema surge ya que estoy intentando recibir un arreglo de hash dentro de otro arreglo de hash, al hacer esto me sale el mensaje:

> Unpermitted parameters: id, importe_ads

en la definición de los parametros tengo lo siguiente:

```
    def payroll_params
        params.permit( 
          payroll: [
            :id, :employee_id, :week_id, :department_id, :dias_trabajados,
            :dias_vacaciones, :faltas, :total_percepciones, :total_retenciones,
            :total_sueldo_bruto, :total_sueldo_neto, :sueldo_fiscal, :pago_impuesto,
            :pago_eps, :tipo_pago_fiscal, :tipo_pago_eps, :created_by, :updated_by,
            :employee_wd_attributes=>[:id,:jueves, :viernes, :sabado, :domingo, :lunes, :martes, :miercoles],
            :employee_wad_attributes=>[:id=>[],:importe_ads=>[]]
          ]
        )
    end
```

El problema es sobre :employee_wad_attributes, adjunto el request resumido a un elemento del arreglo hash de payroll:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí lo que marca el Log:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/IV+a8UngslZ/VXcCmBmG8ndKhzfFLH6NhyqmZ4NctliqP2QA3PLPF2GDP25zLpIpqIRU7kSPlermfhhZ7KuwA==", "payroll"=>[{"id"=>"44", "week_id"=>"39", "department_id"=>"2", "employee_id"=>"1", "employee_wd_attributes"=>{"id"=>"10", "jueves"=>"1", "viernes"=>"0", "sabado"=>"0", "domingo"=>"0", "lunes"=>"0", "martes"=>"0", "miercoles"=>"0"}, "dias_trabajados"=>"0.0", "dias_vacaciones"=>"0", "faltas"=>"0", "total_sueldo_bruto"=>"0.0", "employee_wad_attributes"=>[{"id"=>"1", "importe_ads"=>"3"}, {"id"=>"2", "importe_ads"=>"3"}, {"id"=>"3", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"4", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"5", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"6", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"7", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"8", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"9", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"10", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"11", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"12", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"13", "importe_ads"=>"0"}], "total_percepciones"=>"0.0", "total_retenciones"=>"0.0", "sueldo_fiscal"=>"0.0", "total_sueldo_neto"=>"2"}, {"id"=>"45", "week_id"=>"39", "department_id"=>"2", "employee_id"=>"2", "employee_wd_attributes"=>{"id"=>"11", "jueves"=>"1", "viernes"=>"0", "sabado"=>"0", "domingo"=>"0", "lunes"=>"0", "martes"=>"0", "miercoles"=>"0"}, "dias_trabajados"=>"0.0", "dias_vacaciones"=>"0", "faltas"=>"0", "total_sueldo_bruto"=>"0.0", "employee_wad_attributes"=>[{"id"=>"1", "importe_ads"=>"3"}, {"id"=>"2", "importe_ads"=>"3"}, {"id"=>"3", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"4", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"5", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"6", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"7", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"8", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"9", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"10", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"11", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"12", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"13", "importe_ads"=>"0"}], "total_percepciones"=>"0.0", "total_retenciones"=>"0.0", "sueldo_fiscal"=>"0.0", "total_sueldo_neto"=>"2"}, {"id"=>"46", "week_id"=>"39", "department_id"=>"2", "employee_id"=>"3", "employee_wd_attributes"=>{"id"=>"12", "jueves"=>"1", "viernes"=>"0", "sabado"=>"0", "domingo"=>"0", "lunes"=>"0", "martes"=>"0", "miercoles"=>"0"}, "dias_trabajados"=>"0.0", "dias_vacaciones"=>"0", "faltas"=>"0", "total_sueldo_bruto"=>"0.0", "employee_wad_attributes"=>[{"id"=>"1", "importe_ads"=>"3"}, {"id"=>"2", "importe_ads"=>"3"}, {"id"=>"3", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"4", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"5", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"6", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"7", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"8", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"9", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"10", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"11", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"12", "importe_ads"=>"0"}, {"id"=>"13", "importe_ads"=>"0"}], "total_percepciones"=>"0.0", "total_retenciones"=>"0.0", "sueldo_fiscal"=>"0.0", "total_sueldo_neto"=>"2"}], "commit"=>"guardar", "method"=>"post", "remote"=>"true", "company_id"=>"1", "week_id"=>"39"}
 Unpermitted parameters: id, importe_ads (muchas veces)
 Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, commit, method, remote, company_id, week_id
```

Les agradezco su ayuda y tiempo de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es ocasionado porque, al utilizar `=>[]` en esta línea

```
:employee_wad_attributes=>[:id=>[],:importe_ads=>[]]
```

estás indicando que tanto `:id` como `:importe_ads` son agrupadores, es decir tienen a su vez otro set de llaves, lo cual es incorrecto.

Por lo tanto, simplemente debes indicar las llaves que son permitidas dentro de ese arreglo:

```
:employee_wad_attributes=>[:id, :importe_ads]
```

Considerando lo anterior, así quedaría el método `payroll_params`:

```
def payroll_params
  params.permit( 
    payroll: [
      :id, :employee_id, :week_id, :department_id, :dias_trabajados,
      :dias_vacaciones, :faltas, :total_percepciones, :total_retenciones,
      :total_sueldo_bruto, :total_sueldo_neto, :sueldo_fiscal, :pago_impuesto,
      :pago_eps, :tipo_pago_fiscal, :tipo_pago_eps, :created_by, :updated_by,
      :employee_wd_attributes=>[:id,:jueves, :viernes, :sabado, :domingo, :lunes, :martes, :miercoles],
      :employee_wad_attributes=>[:id,:importe_ads]
    ]
  )
end
```

Comment: Una disculpa por no contestar antes, me quede sin internet pero efectivamente esto soluciono mi problema y funciono correctamente, gracias @Gerry

Answer (score 0):

El problema debe estar en que estás tratando de crear un `Hash` para `:employee_wad_attributes`, pero estás usando `[]` (que es para crear Arreglos)

```
:employee_wad_attributes => [ :id => [], :importe_ads => [] ]
```

Prueba de la siguiente manera:

```
:employee_wad_attributes => { :id => [], :importe_ads => [] }
```